# Get current video play time as a post response from php page

Tags: php, video

This is code for getting current video timing and sending to another php page
I want to call directly **getvideotiming.php** file and I want result as current video time'
below is the code

**video.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video-active" class="video-active" width="640" height="390" controls="controls">
    <source src="trial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="current">0:00</div>
<div id="duration">0:00</div>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#video-active").on(
    "timeupdate", 
    function(event){
      onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime, this.duration);
    });
});

function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime, duration){
    $("#current").text(currentTime); 
    $("#duration").text(duration);
console.log(currentTime); 
        var amount = currentTime;
        $.ajax({
            url: "getvideotiming.php",
            type: 'post',
            data: {"currentTime": amount},
        success: function(response) { console.log("ys"); }
        });     
}
</script>
</head>
```

getvideotiming.php

```
$amount   = isset($_POST['currentTime'])   ? $_POST['currentTime']   : null;
        echo "current time:".$amount;
```

But if I call getvideotiming.php directly then I get null

is there any other way from which i can get current video time from directly calling getvideotiming.php

Comment: Why do you need PHP to tell you the video's current time (_ie:_ what problem does this technique solve)?

Comment: @VC.One This technique is not solving the problem I just want a webservice where I can get current video playing time to client machine. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Is this solved now? I don't know JQuery but to avoid losing time I can provide a pure JS solution if that is acceptable to your project. Also update your Question if anything has changed in code or concept.

Comment: @VC.One
 Yes I solved the problem somehow. In getvideotiming.php i saved currentTime in database & from using another file i.e getplayingtime.php I seletced cuttenttime from database table so that i can call getplayingtime.php without calling getvideotiming.php using webservice